# Reading aligned memory using fast u32 access can lead to strict aliasing issues when paired with inlining

Tags: c, hash, inline, strict-aliasing, memory-access

I've got a function which essentially produces a hash value over an arbitrary memory region.
The input argument uses `const void*` type, as a way to say "this can be anything". So essentially :

```
unsigned hash(const void* ptr, size_t size);
```

so far, so good.

The blob of bytes can be anything, and its start address can be anywhere. Meaning that sometimes, it's aligned on 32-bit boundaries, and sometimes it's not.

On some platforms (`armv6` for example, or `mips`), reading from unaligned memory result in huge performance penalty. It's actually not possible to read 32-bit from unaligned memory directly, so the compiler tends to settle for a safer byte-by-byte recombination algorithm (the exact implementation details are hidden behind a `memcpy()`).

The safe access method is of course *a lot* slower than a direct 32-bit access, which is itself only possible when input data is properly aligned on 32-bit boundary.
This leads to a design trying to separate the 2 cases : when input is unaligned, use the safe access code path, when input is aligned (effectively quite often) use the direct 32-bit access code path.

The difference in performance is huge, we are not talking of a few % here, this translates into a 5x performance increase, sometimes even more. So it's not just "nice", it actually makes the function competitive or not, useful or not.

This design has been working fine so far, in a decent number of scenarios.

Enter inlining.

Now, with the function implementation accessible at compilation time, a clever compiler can peel off all the indirection layers, and reduce the implementation to its essential elements. In the case where it can prove that the input is necessarily aligned, such as a `struct` with defined members, it can simplify the code, remove all the `const void*` indirections, and get down to the barebone implementation where the memory area is effectively read using a `const u32*` pointer.

And now strict-aliasing can kick in, as the input area is written using a `struct S*` ptr, and read using a different `const u32*` ptr, therefore allowing the compiler to consider these 2 operations as completely independent, eventually re-ordering them, leading to an incorrect outcome.

This is essentially the interpretation I received from a user. 
It may worth noting that I was unable to reproduce the issue, but strict-aliasing issues uncovered through inlining, this is a known topic. It is also known that strict aliasing can be difficult to reproduce due to tiny implementation details leading to different optimization choices depending on compiler version. I therefore consider the report as credible, but can't study it directly in absence of a reproduction case.

Anyway, now comes the question. How to handle this case correctly ?
A "safe" solution is to always use the `memcpy()` path, but it craters the performance so much that it makes the function just no longer useful. Plus, it's obviously a terrible waste of energy.
The easy escape is to not inline, though it leads to its own function call overhead (to be fair, not that large), and more importantly just "hides" the problem rather than solve it.

But I've yet to find a solution to it. I've been told that, no matter what kind of intermediate pointer is used, even if a `const char*` is part of the cast chain, this will not prevent the final `const u32*` read operation from violating strict aliasing (just repeating, I can't test it, because I can't reproduce the case).
Described this way, this feels almost hopeless.

But I can't help but note that `memcpy()` can properly avoid such kind of re-ordering risk, even though its interface also uses `const void*`, and exact implementation vary a lot, but we can be certain that it's not just reading byte-by-byte `const char*`, as performance is excellent, and doesn't hesitate using vector code when faster. Also, `memcpy()` is a function which is definitely inlined a lot.
So I guess there must be a solution to this problem.

Comment: How portable does this need to be?  There may be compiler-specific ways to relax the strict aliasing rules.  For instance, gcc and clang have `__attribute__((may_alias))`.

Comment: Are you assuming `unsigned` same as `uint32_t` or do you want portability?

Comment: So far, I believe the `__attribute__((may_alias))` is the best answer, since no _portable_ solution has been found yet (beyond using `memcpy()`, cratering performance in some scenarios as described above).

Answer (score 0):

(`unsigned`) `char` is [exempt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) from strict aliasing rules. No matter what, the following is safe and sane as long as `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`:

```
unsigned hash(const void* ptr, size_t size) {
    const unsigned char* bytes = ptr;

    while (size >= 4) {
        uint32_t x;
        memcpy(&x, bytes, 4);
        bytes += 4;
        size -= 4;

        // Use x.
    }

    // Size leftover bytes.
}
```

Do note that the values of `x` will be dependent on the endianness of your machine. If you require cross-platform consistent hashes you will need to convert to your preferred endianness.

---

Note that if you force alignment you can make the compiler generate fast path code even with `memcpy`:

```
void* align(void* p, size_t n) {
    // n must be power of two.
    uintptr_t pi = (uintptr_t) p;
    return (unsigned char*) ((pi + (n - 1)) & -n);
}

inline uint32_t update_hash(uint32_t h, uint32_t x) {
    h += x;
    return h;
}

unsigned hash(const void* ptr, size_t size) {
    const unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    const unsigned char* aligned_bytes = align((void*) bytes, 4);

    uint32_t h = 0;
    uint32_t x;
    if (bytes == aligned_bytes) {
        // Aligned fast path.
        while (size >= 4) {
            memcpy(&x, bytes, 4);
            h = update_hash(h, x);
            size -= 4;
            bytes += 4;
        }
    } else {
        // Slower unaligned path, copy to aligned buffer.
        while (size >= 4) {
            uint32_t buffer[32];
            size_t bufsize = size < 4*32 ? size / 4 : 32;
            memcpy(buffer, bytes, 4*bufsize);
            size -= 4*bufsize;

            for (int i = 0; i < bufsize; ++i) {
                h = update_hash(h, buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (size) {
        // Assuming little endian.
        x = 0;
        memcpy(&x, bytes, size);
        h = update_hash(h, x);
    }

    return h;
}
```

Comment: This is the `memcpy()` method, which is already in use for the "unaligned memory access" path. And as already mentioned, yes it works, yes it's safe, but it leads to disastrous performance on systems unable to offer decent performance for unaligned memory accesses (`armv6` is a good example; this issue doesn't exist on `x64` or `aarch64`).

Comment: @Cyan [Inspect the assembly generated](https://godbolt.org/z/FJEqFc) and you'll note that the `memcpy` is entirely removed. Note that I'm only `memcpy`ing into one local variable. The alignment can be solved if you are okay with accessing the first couple elements byte-by-byte. If that's not okay you can still `memcpy` chunks at a time into aligned memory.

Comment: @Cyan Noted regarding `armv6`. Your question is basically two in one, I mostly focused on the aliasing problem, which has a very simple fix. Are you okay with accessing the first couple bytes one-by-one followed by `u32` access, or do you need `u32` access throughout for your hash function?

Comment: The question addresses these points.
The input is aligned. It's just that `memcpy()` doesn't care about it, and uses a generic "safe" but ultra-slow access method.
https://godbolt.org/z/vXQESu

Comment: @Cyan I updated my answer with a fast path / slow path example.

Comment: Pedantic "No matter what, the following is safe" --> Not if `sizeof(uint32_t) != 4`.  Just use `sizeof(uint32_t)` instead of 4.

Comment: `align()` assumes a linear relationship between `uintptr_t` and `void *`.  Reasonable, yet not specified by C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica C does not offer any specified way to align pointers AFAIK so meh. Same for `sizeof(uint32_t)` not being 4, then you have bigger problems anyway and this code fails in more ways (good chance `bytes` aren't bytes then anymore either). At some point you have to start assuming some things about your platform.

Comment: I see nothing in your answer that would fail with 4 replaced with `sizeof(uint32_t)` and `sizeof(uint32_t) != 4`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The **only** way `sizeof(uint32_t) != 4` is if `CHAR_BIT != 8` in which case the whole assumption that `unsigned char` is a byte, the hash function's result, little endian, etc, all comes apart.

Comment: OP's question and this answer do not require `CHAR_BIT == 8`.  Code works fine with `CHAR_BIT == 16 or 32`, if 4 was replaced with `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Comment: I've been considering the same idea, giving the compiler a clear signal to realize that the address is aligned, and hope that `memcpy()` get optimized as a single 32-bit read as a result.
But so far, the produced assembly doesn't match this expectation. It's still the same slow byte-by-byte recombination, at best.
One of the risks is that the outcome may depend on the compiler, and some of them are really bad at optimizing `memcpy()`, making this method not universal (if performance matters).

Anyway, I'll gladly take any example of assembly output.

Comment: @Cyan Did you test my method? With GCC on ARM64 it works just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/4vk6p-  Notice the loops .L7 and .L10.

Comment: `aarch64` has no problem with unaligned memory accesses. The situation for this architecture is similar to `x64`, so it doesn't need any "fast path": just using `memcpy()` all the time works fine with `gcc`.
The issue is strictly limited to cpus which suffer an impossibility or crippling performance when accessing unaligned memory, like `armv6` or `mips`.

Comment: @Cyan Then change the compiler to ARM, you'll see it's still using a fast path... Not for MIPS because GCC 5.4 is too outdated it seems.

Comment: @Cyan: For some reason, compiler vendors think it's better to recognize the cases where slow byte-wise code could be converted into faster word-based code, than to extend the language by adding specifications for some "officially" undefined behaviors--something the authors of the Standard deliberately invited implementations to do.  Most of the useful type-punning scenarios would be easy to detect if compiler writers made any effort whatsoever to do so.

Comment: @orlp: Some 32-bit bit ARM architectures also support unaligned accesses.  Try using `-mcpu=Cortex-M0` and examine code generation then.  Actually, I find that gcc and clang have to be dragged kicking and screaming to generate decent code for that platform (e.g. replace constants used within a loop with values loaded from a `static volatile` object) but it should be obvious if code is having to do a sequence of byte loads rather than a word load.

Comment: @Cyan: One of the things that peeves me about gcc/clang refusal to accept type punning constructs is that while they've adopted an abstraction model where such support might be somewhat difficult, that's only because their abstraction model can't handle some cases defined by the C Standard.  Extending the model to actually uphold the C Standard while also allowing common type-punning patterns would actually be easier than upholding the C Standard without allowing common forms of type punning beyond the bare minimum requirements.